# Unix script to assign default values for output fields of a XML input file

Tags: unix, informatica

I have to set default values for the lookup transformation. Default values are stored in separate file.
Input file is in XML format.
So need to write Unix script for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but you've not explained enough e.g. why do the default values have to be stored in a separate file when Informatica already provides your transformation ports with configurable default values?

Comment: Actually when lookup condition (source field = lookup field) is satisfied, then we need to assign some other field from lookup table. Otherwise we need to assign one default value for every fields. Like that, we have to assign this process for more than 50 fields.
If we will do it manually (for every time we have assigned default expression in expression transformation for every output fields), than it takes more time.
So if we have a Unix script for this, then no need to toe for all the transformation ports.

This is why I need Unix script for this.

Comment: That's not a right way to do it. You should assign defaults in Informatica. You can edit the mapping XML and import it to speed up development.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so take your lookup returned port to another expression tramsformation which has all your fields set via iif to be equal to the value they would get set or the desired default value when the lookup returned field is null.